# Scoped Storage android 10.0

Tags: java, android, scoped-storage

Crash is here......

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, bucket_display_name, bucket_id, _id, orientation FROM images WHERE ((is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' ))) AND ((1) GROUP BY 1,(2)) ORDER BY date_modified DESC, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:184)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:955)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:891)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:840)

Below is method to show all folders or album of images.

```
private boolean logGalleryFolders() {
        this.albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> bucketIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id", "bucket_display_name", "bucket_id", "_id", "orientation"}, "1) GROUP BY 1,(2", null, "date_modified DESC");

        List<GridViewItem> items;
        int i;
        if (cur == null || !cur.moveToFirst()) {
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            for (i = 0; i < this.albumList.size(); i++) {
                items.add(new GridViewItem(this.activity, this.albumList.get(i).name, BuildConfig.FLAVOR + this.albumList.get(i).imageIdList.size(), true, this.albumList.get(i).imageIdForThumb, this.albumList.get(i).orientationList.get(0).intValue()));
            }
            this.albumList.add(new Album());
            this.albumList.get(this.albumList.size() - 1).gridItems = items;
            for (i = 0; i < this.albumList.size() - 1; i++) {
                this.albumList.get(i).gridItems = createGridItemsOnClick(i);
            }

            if (cur != null) {
                cur.close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("bucket_display_name");
        int bucketId = cur.getColumnIndex("bucket_id");
        int imageId = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int orientationColumnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex("orientation");
        do {
            Album album = new Album();
            int id = cur.getInt(bucketId);
            album.ID = id;
            if (bucketIdList.contains(id)) {
                Album albumFromList = this.albumList.get(bucketIdList.indexOf(album.ID));
                albumFromList.imageIdList.add(cur.getLong(imageId));
                albumFromList.orientationList.add(cur.getInt(orientationColumnIndex));
            } else {
                String bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                bucketIdList.add(id);
                album.name = bucket;
                album.imageIdForThumb = cur.getLong(imageId);
                album.imageIdList.add(album.imageIdForThumb);
                this.albumList.add(album);
                album.orientationList.add(cur.getInt(orientationColumnIndex));
            }
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; i < this.albumList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(new GridViewItem(this.activity, this.albumList.get(i).name, BuildConfig.FLAVOR + this.albumList.get(i).imageIdList.size(), true, this.albumList.get(i).imageIdForThumb, this.albumList.get(i).orientationList.get(0).intValue()));
        }
        this.albumList.add(new Album());
        this.albumList.get(this.albumList.size() - 1).gridItems = items;
        for (i = 0; i < this.albumList.size() - 1; i++) {
            this.albumList.get(i).gridItems = createGridItemsOnClick(i);
        }
        cur.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Below is crash line......

```
Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id", "bucket_display_name", "bucket_id", "_id", "orientation"}, "1) GROUP BY 1,(2", null, "date_modified DESC");
```

Comment: What does this have to do with scoped storage? Nothing!

Comment: @blackapps   Android 10.0 this crash happen. android 9.0 working fine with the above code why??

Comment: That you have to find out. And as long as you dont know you will not know if it has anything to do with scoped storage. Im pretty shure it has nothing to do with it. You better find a better subject for your post which is about sqlite. There were changes in Android 10 concerning SELECT queries for the media store.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the query like below:

From

```
 Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id", "bucket_display_name", "bucket_id", "_id", "orientation"}, "1) GROUP BY 1,(2", null, "date_modified DESC");
```

To

```
Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id", "bucket_display_name", "bucket_id", "_id", "orientation"}, null, null, "date_modified DESC");
```

Comment: Hi Bony and welcome to StackOverflow. Please enclose your code fragments into code blocks for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GROUP BY` comes inside the `And` makes the issue. Please change your `query` as below:

```
SELECT
  _id,
  bucket_display_name,
  bucket_id,
  _id,
  orientation
FROM
  images
WHERE
  (
    (is_pending = 0)
    AND (is_trashed = 0)
    AND (volume_name IN ('external_primary'))
  )
  AND ((1))
GROUP BY
  1,(2)
ORDER BY
  date_modified DESC
```

Comment: not clear to me i am beginner. Please change above query for solution.

Comment: I don't know your requirement, but the issue you got is based on SQL syntax error. I corrected the syntax error with my answer