# Upgraded to targetSdkVersion 30, struggling with scoped storage implementation

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, scoped-storage

I have taken over an outdated Android App written in Java

I have progressively upgraded dependencies without issue until I changed the targetSdkVersion from 27 to 30.

This is for a feature that:

1. Allows user to pick an from the gallery or capture from camera
2. Saves a value to an application folder
3. Sends the picture to an API

I know that pre-Android 10, I could add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the Manifest file and it would work, but that feature was from Android 10+.

If I downgrade the targetSdkVersion, it works.

Otherwise it throws the following errors:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/xxxxx/1380402_672833029402941_703996746_n.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I have narrowed it down to a permissions issue, due to [scoped storage restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

I understand the concept behind it but I cannot get it to work.

What do I need to do to fix this in Java code, as I don't know how to apply the examples in Kotlin for Java?

I have tried  following some of the answers from below:

Sample app: https://github.com/tinonetic/android-questions-scoped-storages

1. [Write permissions not working - scoped storage Android SDK 30 (aka Android 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189667/write-permissions-not-working-scoped-storage-android-sdk-30-aka-android-11)
2. [Scoped Storage android 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63913196/scoped-storage-android-10-0)
3. [Add image to Media Gallery - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243330/add-image-to-media-gallery-android)

Comment: `Allows user to pick an from the gallery or capture from camera` gives you a content `Uri`. Use that. Copy from the Uri input stream to a file on your app's private storage. There you can do anything you want.

Comment: "but I cannot get it to work" -- then provide a [mcve] and explain in detail what problems you encountered.

Comment: Thank-you @EugenPechanec to where do I copy the input stream?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I have included a link to a GitHub repository with an app that tries to do what I am trying to do

Comment: Link to a github repository is not a viable sample. Don't expect people to sift through entire project.

Comment: More importantly, we do not know what "cannot get it to work" means. You should start by getting rid of `extractPhysicalPathFromUri()` and `getImagePath()`. They are both unreliable and are unnecessary. `BitmapFactory` has `decodeStream()`, and you can get an `InputStream` on the content by calling `getContentResolver().openInputStream()`, supplying your `Uri`. Even better would be to use an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso, and save yourself hundreds of lines of code (not to mention the icky disk I/O on the main application thread).

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage